# How to redirect site to www if www is left off of request

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, url, url-rewriting

We have a site that www.domain.com for example.  If a visitor forgets to put the www on the url request how is the best way to rewrite the URL to www.domain.com?

We are using VS 2008 with VB.Net 3.5

Comment: What is the context? do you mean "how to do that string manipulation" in VS?

Comment: Use a 301 redirect.  http://jesperastrom.com/seo/different-variations-of-redirects-301-302-303-304-etc/

Comment: This should be handled at the DNS level. Make sure that www.example.com and example.com domain settings point to the same IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect it in your Session_Start event in the Global.asax with the following code:

```
    Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the session is started
    If Request.Url.Host.Contains("www.") = False Then
        Session.Abandon()
        Response.Redirect("http://www.domain.com")
    End If

End Sub
```